# How to invoke Pycharm debugger from code?

Tags: python, pycharm, pdb

I see it is possible to invoke pdb debugger from code using:

```
import pdb;    pdb.set_trace()
```

Is there an equivalent for Pycharm debugger? As I would prefer to only learn one debugger. I want to run, rather than debug initially as debug is much slower.

Can I invoke pycharm debugger from a code line in some way?

Comment: You can use Python Debug Server in PyCharm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config (ignore Remote word, it works fine locally).

Comment: You can also use shorthand ```breakpoint()``` for pdb.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to invoke the debugger from your code, think of pycharm as something not related to your code. If you want to invoke debugger from your code, unfortunately pdb is the only way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

In Pycharm you can click next to the line number to turn on a red dot that will symbolize a debug point for that line. It will stop right before executing that line.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html#where-is-the-problem

Comment: It only does that when in debug mode. I want to invoke it from run mode

Comment: You can either use pdb and run or use debug mode and set the debug points. You can't set debug points in run mode in pycharm.